# Infinite Limit Question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am just starting limits, really stumped on this one.

How do I approach this?

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x-2)(x-3)$$

Comment: Hint: Distribute the terms and use properties of limit

Comment: Just check the signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x-2)(x-3)=\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x^2-5x+6)=+\infty$$

That's because it is a polynomial and we look only at the term with the highest degree..

Otherwise,

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x-2)(x-3)=\lim_{x \to -\infty} (x-2) \cdot \lim_{x \to -\infty} (x-3)=(-\infty) \cdot (-\infty)=+\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x<0$,
$$f(x)=(x-2)(x-3)$$
is positive and unbounded, since:
$$ f(x)\geq 6-5x,\tag{1}$$
hence for any $x\leq \frac{6-M}{5}$ we have $f(x)\geq M$, giving that the limit is $+\infty$. $(1)$ is a convexity inequality: $f(x)$ is a convex function and $6-5x=0$ is the equation of the tangent line to the graphics of $f$ in the point $(0,6)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to -\infty} (x-2)(x-3) = \lim_{x\to -\infty} (x^2 - 5x + 6) = \infty $

In simple terms, you have a really large negative number squared minus that same really large negative number times five plus an insignificantly small number 6. One might say that the result is infinitely large. Thus the result is infinity.